# How do I configure a Trackpoint, so middle-click scrolling is not misinterpreted as a middle-click paste?

Tags: mouse, clipboard, thinkpad, scrolling

I'm using a Thinkpad USB Trackpoint keyboard, and when I try to scroll, using middle-click and the trackpoint, sometimes it performs a middle-click paste.  I don't recall this ever happening with the built in keyboard on my laptop.

Is there a way to configure the middle "mouse" button, so it doesn't misinterpret middle click scrolling as a middle click paste?

Note:
I don't want to disable the middle mouse button.  I want to be able to scroll.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here is the Ubuntu Wiki entry on how to disable the middle mouse button.](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Input#Example:_Disabling_middle-mouse_button_paste_on_a_scrollwheel_mouse) This should work on any system using X.

> **Example: Disabling middle-mouse button paste on a scrollwheel mouse**
>
> Scrollwheel mice support a middle-button click event when pressing the
>   scrollwheel. This is a great feature, but you may find it irritating.
>   Fortunately it can be disabled.
>
> First, you need to know the id of the mouse, like this:
>
> ```
> $ xinput list | grep 'id='
>
> "Virtual core pointer"  id=0    [XPointer]
> "Virtual core keyboard" id=1    [XKeyboard]
> "AT Translated Set 2 keyboard"  id=2    [XExtensionKeyboard]
> "Macintosh mouse button emulation"      id=3    [XExtensionPointer]
> "Logitech USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse"       id=4    [XExtensionPointer]
> ```
>
> My mouse has the Logitech logo printed on it, so I gather I need the
>   last entry.
>
> I can view the current button mapping thusly:
>
> ```
> $ xinput get-button-map 4
>
> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 10
> ```
>
> Really, only the first three numbers have meaning for me. They
>   represent the left, middle, and right mouse buttons.
>
> ```
> $ xinput get-button-map 4
> ```
>
> I can turn the middle mouse button off by setting it to 0:
>
> ```
> $ xinput set-button-map 4 1 0 3
> ```
>
> Or I can turn the middle-mouse button into a left-mouse button by
>   setting it to 1:
>
> ```
> $ xinput set-button-map 4 1 1 3
> ```
>
> To make this set on a per-user basis, I can plug that line into my
>   ~/.xstartup or other init file. It can also be done via configuring a
>   matching InputClass section on xorg.conf.

The above example does not disable scrolling; if you want to do that see [here](http://onethingwell.org/post/8779215052/reverse-scrolling-x11).

Comment: I don't want to disable the middle mouse button.  I want to be able to scroll.

Comment: The middle mouse button is the button not the scrolling part. try it and see if it works. The scrolling function is registered differently if you looked at the example there was over 25 different input actions. try it.

Comment: Must of missunderstood.  I'll try it. :)

Comment: Sweet, it worked.

Comment: please improve this answer and give the method within the answer. I would like to solve this issue and the link doesn't help. thanks

Comment: @MountainX  I usually do the following now a days.  ```xinput --list``` to find the id of the trackpoint pointer (say id=10), then ```xinput --set-button-map 10 1 0 3```.  If you wan to re-enable it, do ```xinput --set-button-map 10 1 2 3```.  This doesn't preserve middle click, to open new tab, in firefox though.

Comment: @jumpnett: thanks, I tried that and it did not work. Can you think of a reason why that method would not work? (The xorg.conf method does work, but it is fairly outdated.)

Comment: @MountainX not sure

Comment: "The above example does not disable scrolling", its such a pity they don't mention this at the wiki. I think it confuses many people who have this (indeed frustrating) problem with their trackpoint mouse. I don't use Ubuntu, so I don't feel like creating an account and edit the wiki just to fix that.

Comment: @jumpnett did you ever figure out how to preserve the "open as new tab" behaviour in Firefox?

Comment: @PrunusPersica I don't have this issue with my current installation, so I haven't messed with this in a year or so.  I don't recall ever resolving that issue though.  Sorry I couldn't be of any help.

Answer (score 0):

With Ubuntu 17 and in XFCE the middle mouse button copy paste did not work at all. Same applies for Fedora 26 XFCE, same solution works for Fedora 26 Middle Mouse Button Paste (q.e.d.):

#### SOLUTION

To enable the middle mouse button paste function edit the xinput.

1. Query your device to identify your mouse (mine was listed as device 10):

   ```
   xinput list
   ```
2. List mouse settings:

   ```
   xinput list-props <your_mouse_device_number>
   ```
3. Change the value for "libinput Middle Emulation Enabled (294):" (as root):

   ```
   sudo xinput set-prop 10 "libinput Middle Emulation Enabled" 1
   ```
4. Check if the value changed to 1:

   ```
   xinput list-props 10
   ```

The output should be `libinput Middle Emulation Enabled (294):  1`

Many, many thanks to Gilles (https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/885/gilles) who found the solution!

Read more: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Input